# Free shipping for payment method

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, free-shipping

I want to automatically make shipping free if user select one specific payment method. Is there any extension to do this or do i have to code one myself, if so where should i start.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use extension for it. You just need to create a shopping cart promotional rule for it.

1) Goto Promotions >> Shopping Cart Price Rules

2) In the Conditions tab select Payment Method which you want to make it as free. Check the screenshot below

[image]

3) Goto Actions tab and mark free shipping as For Shipment with matching items. Please check below screenshot

[image]

Save the rule and thats it, the shipping will be free for selected payment method.

Comment: Can you help me to understand what does "For shipment with matching items" means ?